# Shapekeys Drivers

Tags: animation, drivers, shape-keys

[Blend File](https://easyupload.io/a24dn5)

[image]

I made my first shapekey react to the left tight X rotation , but it's isn't perfect , how can i fix this? The shapekey's deformation do not start soon enough.

PS: Left thigh forward rotation only for now , once i understand how it work i will set the other shapekeys

Answer (score 1):

Right click your driven value → Open Driver Editor

[image]

This will open a graph editor with a curve that goes from bottom left to top right.

The horizontal axe is the driver's value, and the vertical axe is the driven value. You can change the curve's keys coordinates and also deform so that the driven value is as you want depending the driver value. In your case, if you want to make the change happen sooner, you probably want to deform the curve by moving the keyframes' handles:

[image]